# Recovering assets on ZKsync Gnosis Safe

Tags: safe-core

I acidentally sent assets to a ZKsync address. Is there a way to deploy a ZKsync Safe using the same address from my Ethereum Safe? In the past I have done it in other chains, but on ZKsync its not working.
I know there is an incompatibility in bytecodes from Ethereum and ZKsync.

I have reached out to Gnosis Safe support, referencig this article:

"Since the bytecode differs from Ethereum as zkSync uses a modified version of the EVM, the address derived from the bytecode hash will also differ. This means that the same bytecode deployed on Ethereum and zkSync will have different addresses and the Ethereum address will still be available and unused on zkSync. If and when the zkEVM reaches parity with the EVM, the address derivation will be updated to match Ethereum and the same bytecode will have the same address on both chains, deployed bytecodes to different addresses on zkSync could then be deployed to the same the Ethereum-matching addresses on zkSync"

https://era.zksync.io/docs/reference/architecture/differences-with-ethereum.html#create-create2

So, in the future, is there any possibility for those assets to be recovered by restoring the address?

Comment: The answer is in the article you referred to: "If and when".

Comment: Did you ever get feedback on that question? The same happened to me...

Answer (score 1):

For now, since ZkSync and the EVM differ in how they calculate addresses, this is not possible. I haven't see any news of ZkSync converging to the same derivation method used in the EVM, so unless they do, I am afraid this will remain not possible.

Hope it helps,
Louis